# VB.NET - how to do this form effect?

Tags: vb.net, forms, effect

i know about Form.show , and form opacity or using visible control.
but i have never seen such effect, were you can flip the page to show the second form.
this GIF will explain what i'm talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRzOF.gif

Comment: That's WPF, not WinForms.

Comment: Here's an example of how to do this in WPF: http://eren.ws/2013/10/31/creating-a-card-flip-effect-with-blend-boredom-challenge-day-27/

Answer (score 0):

These effects are supported very well in **WPF** or any other framework that uses xml|xaml for designing.
These effects are not easy to show in old fashioned frameworks like Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

For WinForms you have to use GDI. (Nothing for beginners)
Some effects (and a similar you want to implement) can be found under this article:
[codeproject: Animator for WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548769/Animator-for-WinForms)